# Buffer of requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, buffer

I've developed a REST-API using Node and ExpressJS and I need to make a temporary buffer to compare the data received by the requests during X seconds.

For example, the server receives a request, stores it inside the buffer and starts the timer. While the timer isn't done, all the requests data will be stored in that buffer too. When the timer is done, I need to compare all the data inside the buffer and then send it to a database.

My problem is that I don't know if it is possible to implement using node and express, I searched but I didn't find any possible solution for me. Maybe someone can help me to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: You mean you'd like to build some kind of request-recording feature that is active for a specific amount of time? How would the timer be triggered? Every 5 minutes for 1 minute for example? Or by a specific request?

Comment: That's it friend, but I need that the timer to be triggered when the server receives a request and the buffer is empty. After X seconds this buffer would be used to compare and then emptied again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are libraries to do this, but in case you want to implement it yourself, here's what you could do:

You could write a little Request-Recorder class that exposes a `recordData` method, which allows you to record request-data if the recorder is currently active or if there has not been recorded any data yet. If the latter case is true, you enable a timer and let it record data until the timeout is reached. Something like this should help you get started:

```
class RequestDataRecorder {
    static instance;

    constructor() {
        this.isActive = false;
        this.isLocked = false;
        // could also be a map, holding request data by request-id for example
        this.recordedData = [];
        this.recordDataDurationInSeconds = 10; // will capture request data within 10 second time frames
    }

    static shared() {
        if (!RequestDataRecorder.instance) {
            RequestDataRecorder.instance = new RequestDataRecorder();
        }
        return RequestDataRecorder.instance;
    }

    recordData(data) {
        if (this.canActivate()) {
            this.activate();
        }
        if (this.isCurrentlyActive()) {
            this.recordedData.push(data);
        }
    }

    canActivate() {
        return !this.isLocked && !this.isActive && this.recordedData.length === 0;
    }

    activate() {
        this.isLocked = true;
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                this.deactivate();
                this.exportData();
            }, this.recordDataDurationInSeconds * 1000);
        this.isLocked = false;
        this.setActive(true);
    }

    deactivate() {
        this.isLocked = true;
        this.setActive(false);
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.recordedData = [];
        this.isLocked = false;
    }

    setActive(val) {
        this.isActive = val;
    }

    isCurrentlyActive() {
        return this.isActive;
    }

    exportData() {
        // do your db-export here or use another class to to the export with this data (preferably the latter to comply with the single-responsibilty principle :))
        return this.recordedData;
    }

}
```

You can use this class like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
const requestDataRecorder = RequestDataRecorder.shared();

app.post("/postSomeData", (req, res) => {
    requestDataRecorder.recordData(req.body);
    res.status(201).end();
});

app.get("/getRecordedData", (req, res) => {
    res.send(requestDataRecorder.getRecordedData());
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server is listening!");
});
```

Comment: Wow friend, thanks a lot, that's exactly what I need.